# Cron Maker for Quartz.Net

Tags: cron, cronexpression

I was trying to use CRON Maker in my project. I need to do UI based scheduling using CRON Makers. Example site [Click here](http://www.cronmaker.com/). In my UI, there are some schedules where the user can select any kind. Below are some possibilities.

1. One Time ( Start date, Time)
2. Daily ( Start date & Time, Recur Every --- days (Say: -5- days)
3. Weekly ( Start date & Time, Recur Every --- Weeks on Sun, Mon, Tue (Say: -2- weeks).
4. Monthly ( Start date & Time, Date (1-31), Month (1-12).

   I have done the CRON expression for Monthly schedule. I dont know how to make the CRON expression for the rest of the cases. Please help me for this.

   Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can below CRON expression generators:

https://github.com/onterumahendra/CronScheduler

https://github.com/onterumahendra/CronScheduler-Foundation

These are well suited if you are using Quartz Scheduler in the back-end. It generates the CRON expressions and populate the CRON expressions in UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cron syntax does not support weeks (or any similar construct such as day of year). There is a day of month field, with which one could approximate the n-weekly behaviour.

For the days directive you can use the second field (day of week).

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Format

Comment: What might be the possibilities for this case?